# apple clang 12 vector<float> noexcept check fails

Tags: c++, clang, c++20, noexcept

The question is very simple. I am using Apple Clang 12 and this fails:

```
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<std::vector<float>>);
```

I cannot figure out why even by navigating their macros in the source code to determine whether noexcept is truly active in my configuration (it should). It seems that depend on an internal cpp version > 14 but it is 18... not sure what else could be wrong.

Error:

```
    static_assert failed due to requirement 'std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<std::__1::vector<float, std::__1::allocator<float> > >'
static_assert(std::is_nothrow_move_assignable_v<std::vector<float>>);
^             ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: This looks like a compiler bug to me.

Comment: Which specific C++ standard version are you asking about? C++11 or C++20? Or are you comparing differences between the two versions? If asking about a specific version then please tag only that.

Comment: I am asking for c++20

Comment: https://godbolt.org/z/aE6dbhsn3 will check apple clang soon.

Comment: Does @MarekR's code fail to compile for you Germán ? If not, please provide a [mre].

Comment: It is fine for me on `Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.4)` (old machine, currently I do not have access to new one).

Comment: @MarekR Seems to work fine on 14.0.0 as well

Comment: I wonder why this question is vote up? `this fails` is not a description of a problem (many beginners are criticized for such luck of information). Nobody who tried was able to reproduce anything suspicious. There is some claim about `macros` by there are no any macros in question. No reaction when asking about more data (just C++20 was added in comment). So basically question has poor quality which should not happen in case such experienced user.

Comment: @MarekR 100% agreement. I voted to close as non-reproducible.

Comment: @MarekR and noone tried with my setup. What I list there is all you need to reproduce it under my compiler version. That said. I will edit now that small detail.

Comment: @MarekR trying to reproduce things in another version of compilers does not tell you absolutely anything about the error I am getting myself. So it is unfair to just close it and get done with it when it is a fact that the problem is there.

Comment: I've just tried with `Apple clang version 12.0.0 (clang-1200.0.32.29)` with same outcome (using C++17). And what is more interesting this version of clang do not accepts `-std=c++20`! So you had to messed up something.

Comment: I've used code from godbolt link saved it in `test.cpp` and used this command `clang++ -std=c++17 -c test.cpp` is fully successful.

Comment: and it is fine with `-std=c++2a`

Comment: I am using -std=c++2a flag. I said c++20 bc I am using meson, but it maps to -std=c++2a in the command-line.

Comment: My version of clang is clang-1200.0.32.29

Comment: Surprisingly... the minimal example works. But the static assert in my code does not...

Comment: GermánDiago Again: Supply a [mre]. If @MarekR 's code compiles, but your own does not, what are the differences?

Comment: We can delete the question or I can post a reply. The problem was that defaulting a destructor was affecting copy and move defaults for my class that contained vector<float>. Another strange thing that happened is that without including type_traits the static_assert compiled but failed... those were the problems basically.